# Localization of a double category

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $C:=(C_0,C_1, id, s,t, \circ)$ be a double category, i.e. a category object in the category of small categories.
Let $W$ be a set of morphisms in $C_1$ whose elements are sent to isomorphisms by $s,t$ and are preserved by composition $\circ$.

Is there a localization double category $C[W]$ (not necessarily small) with the respective universal property of localization such that $C[W]_0 = C_0, C[W]_1 = C_1[W]$?

In other words is it true that the functor
$\alpha: (B,W) \mapsto B[W]$ from small categories equipped with sets of morphisms
to large categories preserves category objects?

Moreover we can assume that $C_0$ is a groupoid.

I guess this is not formal since $\alpha$ does not preserve pullbacks
but I could image that $\alpha$ preserves the pullbacks in the definition of
category objects since these pullbacks are so simple.